# Match expression and replace

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a string like `This-is-${username}` I want to match `${username}` and replace it with value **Tom**. I am trying following code and many other but no success.

```
String str = "This-is-${username}";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[/^${*}$/]", "Tom"));
```

Edit: There can be any value between `${}` currently its username between `${}`

Comment: Do you want to replace any substring of type `${SOMETHING}` or only `${username}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\\$\\{[^}]*\\}`

```
String pattern = "\\$\\{[^}]*\\}";

String str1 = "This-is-${username}";
System.out.println(str1.replaceAll(pattern, "Tom"));


String str2 = "This-is-${something}-again";
System.out.println(str2.replaceAll(pattern, "Tom"));
```

Output

```
This-is-Tom
This-is-Tom-again
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, while the idea is somewhat in the right direction, the way you wrote the regex is not.

`[/^${*}$/]` is a character class and will match any one of `/^${*}$/`, which means it is equivalent to `[/^${*}]`.

What would be better is probably this regex:

```
str.replaceAll("\\$\\{[^}]*}", "Tom")
```

You need to escape `$` because otherwise it would mean 'end of line'.

`[^}]` is a negated class and will match all characters except a closing brace.

Answer (score 3):

By placing the pattern you are trying to match inside of a character class `[]`, it's matching each character here. And even by removing the pattern from the character class it will fail to match.

You don't need delimiter's `/`at all, you can remove the beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors because your pattern is not at either place in your data. And the `*` quantifier is not doing what you think it is in this case.

You can use the following, you must escape `\\` the literal `$`, and `{` here.

```
String str = "This-is-${username}";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\$\\{[^}]*}", "Tom"));

// => "This-is-Tom"
```

See [`Working demo`](http://ideone.com/jJ8c41)

Explanation:

```
\$        '$'
\{        '{'
 [^}]*    any character except: '}' (0 or more times)
}         '}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use:

```
str.replaceAll("\\$\\{username\\}", "Tom")
```

Note the escaped `{` and `}` characters.

If you wish to replace any string of form `\\${someString}`, you should use:

```
str.replaceAll("\\$\\{[^}]+\\}", "Tom")
```

Explained:

- `\\$` - match a `$` sign
- `\\{` - match an opening brace
- `[^}]+` - match anything, but a curly brace, one or multiple times
- `\\}` - match a closing brace

Note:

- Since `{`, `}` and `$` are special regex characters, you have to escape them with `\` inside a regular expression to match them as strings.
- We use `\\` inside the `"` because in java `"\\"` produces the string`\`

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
String str = "This-is-${username}";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\$\\{username\\}", "Tom"));
```